# In Python with Pandas how to shift through an Index of unknown frequency using a dictonary

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have been racking my brain for many days on how to solve this.  Please let me know if my approach is totally un-Pythonic or there is a way to do this in Pandas.  I have been trying to shift or tshift through a DataFrame index by one 'shift' from a subset of slices in a dictionary 'lix'.

```
index =
    pd.date_range(start='2014-01-01',freq='B',periods=5) +
    pd.date_range(start='2014-02-04',freq='B',periods=7) +
    pd.date_range(start='2014-03-20',freq='B',periods=11)
so = pd.DataFrame(data=np.nan,index=index,columns=['IBM','Calc'])
lix = {}
lix['A']=so.index[:5]
lix['B']=so.index[5:10]
lix['C']=so.index[10:15]
lix['D']=so.index[15:]
```

The 'index' above has no pattern or frequency, its simply ever increasing set of dates.  The slices of 'so' DataFrame.index are all in a dictionary.  I would like to take lix['A'] slice and shift it by one forward, but per so.index.  Then I would take lix['B'] and shift it by one forward etc.  For example, I can get the end of the slice and use pd.datetools.BDay(1) to offset the end by one Business day, but that's not what is in so.index, so how to add one shift such that the result lands on a valid date from so.index?

```
ts= lix['A'][-1]
ts + pd.datetools.BDay(1)
```

EDIT:  slicing of the original so.index is just for illustration, I can't predict how so.index is sliced into a dictionary. re shift:  pd.Series.shift(so['IBM'][lix['A']]) will return a DataFrame with the data shifted by one forward, but the idea is to get the shifted Index.  Thanks

Comment: Have you tried [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html#pandas.Series.shift)

Comment: Slicing again is not possible? `so.index[:5]` -> ``so.index[1:6]``?